# optional parameters must appear after all required parameters in c#

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

**Method 1**

```
public List<IndentItems> GetIndentsByStatus(string projectAddress, string jobAddress, string currentStatus,string ddlevent)    
{    
    List<IndentItems> indentItems =null;
    indentItems = GetIndentFilledInfo(filterdReports, false,null ,ddlevent);
    return indentItems;    
}
```

**Method 2**

```
public List<IndentItems> GetIndentFilledInfo(List<SurveyFeedback> surveyFeedbacks, bool hasupdate, string indentType = null,string ddlevent)    
{
}
```

From Method1 I'm calling the second method and in method2 based on `EventID` I will get data. But it was showing Compiler Error Message:

> CS1737: Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters.

Comment: Reade here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/331512-optional-parameter-must-appear-after-required-one/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because using a little effort in searching the author could find thousands of explanation

Comment: Keep in mind that nullable properties will always be the last ones defined.

Answer (score 16):

You need to move your optional parameters to the end of the parameter list:

from MSDN:

> Optional parameters are defined at the end of the parameter list,
>   after any required parameters. If the caller provides an argument for
>   any one of a succession of optional parameters, it must provide
>   arguments for all preceding optional parameters. Comma-separated gaps
>   in the argument list are not supported. For example, in the following
>   code, instance method ExampleMethod is defined with one required and
>   two optional parameters.

```
public List<IndentItems> GetIndentFilledInfo(
        List<SurveyFeedback> surveyFeedbacks, 
        bool hasupdate,
        string ddlevent,
        string indentType = null)
```

More Read [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

optional params should be after all of you method params:

```
public List<IndentItems> GetIndentFilledInfo(
    List<SurveyFeedback> surveyFeedbacks, 
    bool hasupdate, 
    string ddlevent,
    string indentType = null)    
{
    // Codes here
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)